# How do I get Excel to use **truly** relative addressing

Tags: excel

I have a complex spreadsheet, but I can summarise what I want with a simple example:

Say I want a budget spreadsheet. I have four columns:

```
        A           B          C             D    
1:  Date       What            Amount  $1,000.00
```

That last is a quick-n-dirty: it actually should be "Balance", but I put my current bank balance there as a starting point...

The next few rows are my future expected expenditures:

```
        A           B          C             D    
1:  Date       What            Amount  $1,000.00
2:  1 Jul 16   Electricity   -$230.00     =D1+C2  (shows   $770.00)
3:  3 Jul 16   Gas           -$144.15     =D2+C3  (shows   $625.85)
4:  4 Jul 16   Pay         +$2,000.00     =D3+C4  (shows $2,625.85)
```

This all works, and it's standard Excel. Especially note that the final column uses "relative addressing" - that is, if you copy row `4` down Excel automatically changes the new cells to indicate what you want: "the cell immediately above here added to the cell immediately to the left of here". If I didn't want relative addressing - that is, I always wanted "Column `B`" or "Row `1`" (or both), then I could put a dollar sign `$` in front of the appropriate part.

Only... it's not *truly* relative. If I were to swap rows `3` and `4` using Cut-n-Paste (Gas bill's not due until the 6th!), Excel will do its darnedest to keep the formula "anchored" to where it previously was...

```
        A           B          C             D    
1:  Date       What            Amount  $1,000.00
2:  1 Jul 16   Electricity   -$230.00     =D1+C2  (shows   $770.00)
3:  4 Jul 16   Pay         +$2,000.00     =D4+C3  (shows $2,625.85)
4:  6 Jul 16   Gas           -$144.15     =D2+C4  (shows   $625.85)
```

...when what I *want* is for it to keep the relativity-ness (sorry, Einstein!):

```
        A           B          C             D    
1:  Date       What            Amount  $1,000.00
2:  1 Jul 16   Electricity   -$230.00     =D1+C2  (shows   $770.00)
3:  4 Jul 16   Pay         +$2,000.00     =D2+C3  (shows $2,770.00)
4:  6 Jul 16   Gas           -$144.15     =D3+C4  (shows $2,625.85)
```

Worse, when the event finally occurs I want to update my bank balance in `$D$1` and delete the row in question. Excel immediately puts error messages in all of Column `D`! It's 'realised' that the referred cell has vanished, so it just gives up - when again what I want is that each cell merely adopts its new "immediately above" cell.

So how do I make the formula ***truly*** relative?

Comment: Consider a different approach for your problem.  Change the date in row 3, then sort your table by that column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I didn't realise that Sort didn't try to keep those anchors. Cool! Unfortunately it doesn't help the more common Delete Row problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a named range. I first learned this years ago from a [John Walkenbach post](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/naming_techniques/). See the section called "Named References." Here's a simple example:

Create a name called "CellAboveAndToTheLeft" or something shorter :-). Make it a relative reference to the cell one up and to the left of the active cell.

[image]

The formula `=CellAboveAndToTheLeft` will refer to the cell one up and to the left of whatever cell it's entered in. This is because of the relative referencing.

[image]

If you delete or remove rows it adjusts correctly. I imagine there are ways to break it, but it's pretty robust.

[image]

Comment: And _this_ answer has it all: the mechanism I needed (without the problem of volatility - thanks @StevenMartin); applicability to other problems (almost a macro!); and learning something new about Excel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a formula in a cell that adds the cell above it to the cells to the left of it, then:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))
```

[image]

*(Of course, no one would do it this way !)*

Comment: Why wouldn't I do it this way? Given that the "standard" way doesn't work for me, perhaps this does? Do you know if `INDIRECT()` or `ADDRESS()` is "volatile", as @StevenMartin describes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027990/how-do-i-get-excel-to-use-truly-relative-addressing/38028220#comment63496205_38027991 ?

Comment: @JohnBurger  See https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/

Comment: Thanks for that. I now understand what you meant about "_No one would do it this way_"...

Answer (score 1):

> While typing the above question I thought that there might be a formula that does what I want - and I found it! So as not to waste an interesting question...

Rather than using straightforward cell references, use `OFFSET()` instead. Given that you're moving or deleting whole rows, any reference out of the current row should be relative to the current cell - you can maintain normal references inside the same row.

`OFFSET()` takes three parameters:

- The cell from which to offset from - for your example, use the current cell;
- How many rows from that cell to offset - for your example, use `-1`;
- How many columns from that cell to offset - for your example, use `0`.

Thus:

```
        A           B          C             D    
1:  Date       What            Amount  $1,000.00
2:  1 Jul 16   Electricity   -$230.00     =OFFSET(D2,-1,0)+C2  (shows   $770.00)
3:  4 Jul 16   Pay         +$2,000.00     =OFFSET(D3,-1,0)+C3  (shows $2,770.00)
4:  6 Jul 16   Gas           -$144.15     =OFFSET(D4,-1,0)+C4  (shows $2,625.85)
```

Because the cell references that are inside the `OFFSET()` formula are of the exact cell, then copying, moving or deleting the cell maintains the 'relativity-ness' just like you want.

Comment: Keep in mind OFFSET is volatile and will recalculate every time a cell is changed which will cause performance issues on large sheets.

Comment: @StevenMartin: Ooooo, I wasn't aware of that! Thanks